# FlickR API - Query Based on EditText

Tags: java, android, rest, flickr

I have successfully determined how to make a call to the FlickR API. However, I am having difficulty determining how I search all of the FlickR photos based on a search term entered by the user.

I believe the search term should be entered into the "tags" component of the [FlickR API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html), however I do not know how to link my Edit Text variable (mQuery) to the FlickR API tag:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mSearchTerm;
private Button mRequestButton;
private String mQuery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSearchTerm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ediText_search_term);
    mRequestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request_button);
    mRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mQuery = mSearchTerm.getText().toString();
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/")
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();


            ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<List<Photo>> call = apiInterface.getPhotos(mQuery);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Photo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Photo>> call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Photo>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }
    });



}

//Synchronous vs. Asynchronous
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("?&method=flickr.photos.search&tags=<Ali>&api_key=1c448390199c03a6f2d436c40defd90e&format=json")  //
    Call<List<Photo>> getPhotos(@Query("q") String photoSearchTerm);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, this is a search API for Flickr

```
  public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.flickr.com/";

  @GET("services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key="+API_KEY+"&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_m")
  Call<FlickrModel> getImages(@Query("text") String query);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how is the EditText incorporated?

Comment: you are doing the Retrofit initialization wrong here

Comment: https://github.com/Veeresh8/FlickrAPI check this repo, which has every thing you need

Comment: Wow thanks, I will certainly take a look and let you know if I have any other questions

Comment: You've been extremely helpful, I was wondering if you could recommend a tutorial on how to search for images within the Android app and then populate the results into a GridView?

Comment: can you share your email, we can discuss this further

Comment: yes, really appreciate your help, you can contact me tccpg288@gmail.com

Comment: I have also created another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113335/how-to-access-child-item-in-json-array

Comment: Can you shoot me an e-mail? Also, I am having a new issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261661/null-responses-using-retrofit-calls