# How to Access Child Item In JSON Array

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, flickr

I am querying FlickR based on certain search terms, and the response is a JSON Array. Here is the root level along with the first two results:

```
{
 photos: {
   page: 1,
   pages: 4222,
   perpage: 100,
   total: "422175",
      photo: [
          {
          id: "28571356563",
          owner: "8372889@N03",secret: "c4ca6c4364",
          server: "8050",
          farm: 9,
          title: "95040021.jpg",
          ispublic: 1,
          isfriend: 0,
          isfamily: 0,
          url_m: "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8050/28571356563_c4ca6c4364.jpg",
          height_m: "332",
          width_m: "500"
               },
          {
          id: "28571342883",
          owner: "96125450@N00",
          secret: "db35a59412",
          server: "8307",
          farm: 9,
          title: "Red #Sunset #Silhouette #Trees #Photography",
          ispublic: 1,
          isfriend: 0,
          isfamily: 0,
          url_m: "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8307/28571342883_db35a59412.jpg",
          height_m: "500",
          width_m: "424"
            },
```

When I load the results, I am going to iterate through all items (the "total" figure) and load into a RecyclerView.

Ultimately, I want to iterate through the "photos" and then get the "url_m" for each photo. Here is my current call to the FlickR API through Retrofit:

```
 Call<List<Photo>> call = apiInterface.getImages(mQuery);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Photo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Photo>> call, Response<List<Photo>> response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Photo>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

How would I iterate through all photos and get the URL for each photo? I have my model classes set up for each that map exactly to the FlickR API JSON objects:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're implementing wrong Retrofit callback in your code. As I can see you're receiving first a JSONObject called `photos` that contains a JSONArray `photo`, so your code should look like this

```
Call<PhotoResult> call = apiInterface.getImages(query);
call.enqueue(new Callback<PhotoResult>() {...}
```

As you can see, the callback object is `PhotoResult` that is the root level of your json response, and inside you should retrieve the `List<Photo>` collection.

To generate your POJOs you can use this website
`http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/`

Your POJOs should be like this

```
public class PhotoResult {
    @SerializedName("photos")
    @Expose
    public Photos photos;
}

public class Photos {
    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    public Integer page;
    @SerializedName("pages")
    @Expose
    public Integer pages;
    @SerializedName("perpage")
    @Expose
    public Integer perpage;
    @SerializedName("total")
    @Expose
    public String total;
    @SerializedName("photo")
    @Expose
    public List<Photo> photo = new ArrayList<Photo>();
}

public class Photo {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Based on the JSON, wouldn't it be Call<photos> then?

Comment: Your first POJO should parse the `photos` JSONObject, that POJO will contain the list of `photos` objects

Comment: So based on that logic, if I wanted to access the "total" item (assuming I already have my JSON mapped to Java), what would I enter into the Callback code?

Comment: In my edited answer are some samples of how your POJOs should look like (add getters and setters if you like), then in your callback you'll receive the `PhotoResult` object, that contains `Photos`, and that one contains the `List<Photo>`

Comment: To access the `total` value you just have to assign like this `response.body().photos.total`.

Comment: Please see the included post, I have used your advice and am still having some issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261481/nullpointer-when-accessing-json-response

Comment: Answered in the new post